# Error with plotting line with matplotlib on tkinter Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I made a program with tkinter that takes values from treeview, puts them into numpy array lists (`Xprojekti, Yprojekti`) and then plots the graph on tkinter window.
Values in these 2 lists are not in order, but I want to plot them so that values on the axis are in order. When I try to do that I get this error:

```
    for seg in self._plot_args(this, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 384, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 243, in _xy_from_xy
    "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (50,) and (3,)
```

What should I do?

```
Xprojekti=np.array([])
Yprojekti=np.array([])

for child in tree.get_children():
    ProjectSize=round(float(tree.item(child,"values")[1]),2)
    Xprojekti=np.append(Xprojekti, ProjectSize)

for child in tree.get_children():
    ProjectCost=round(float(tree.item(child,"values")[3]),2)
    Yprojekti=np.append(Yprojekti, ProjectCost)

X=np.linspace(np.min(Xprojekti), np.max(Xprojekti))  # I used this to sort the values on X

fprojekti=Figure(figsize=(6.5, 4.2),dpi=83)
grafikprojekti=fprojekti.add_subplot(111)

grafikprojekti.plot(X, Yprojekti, color="blue",marker="o", linewidth=1)
grafikprojekti.set_xlabel("Size")
grafikprojekti.set_ylabel("Costs")
grafikprojekti.set_title("All projects")
grafikprojekti.grid()

canvasprojects=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fprojekti, master=Database)
canvasprojects.show()
canvasprojects.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="wn",padx=5)

toolbar_frameprojekti=Frame(Database)
toolbar_frameprojekti.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky="wn",padx=5)

toolbarprojects = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvasprojects,toolbar_frameprojekti)
toolbarprojects.update()
canvasprojects._tkcanvas.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="wn",padx=5,pady=10)
```

Comment: Hi. It would help to either include the full stack-trace or a complete self-contained example. Given the error messages, I assume the error is on the line `grafikprojekti.plot(X, Yprojekti, color="blue",marker="o", linewidth=1)`. Is it correct ?

Comment: Well I guess that its in that line. I tried to delete this line (X=np.linspace(`np.min(Xprojekti), np.max(Xprojekti))`) , and to plot Xprojekti and Yprojekti. Then it works, but the X values are not in order, the line goes all over the graph

Comment: Please read and understand [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `linspace`is not a sort function. It returns evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)). The easiest way to solve the problem is to:

1. Extract a list of tuple (x,y) from the tree
2. Sort this list
3. Create the x and y list, in the correct order

The following code should do the trick (untested as I don't have a `tree` object)

```
# Get a list of points
points = []
for child in tree.get_children():
    points.append((float(tree.item(child,"values")[1]), 
                   float(tree.item(child,"values")[3])))
# Sort the points
points = sorted(point)
# Extract X and Y 
X = [v[0] for v in points]
Y = [v[1] for v in points]
# And now the rest of our code
projekti=Figure(figsize=(6.5, 4.2),dpi=83)
grafikprojekti=fprojekti.add_subplot(111)
grafikprojekti.plot(X, Y, color="blue",marker="o", linewidth=1)
```

A few comments:

1. I didn't round the value at two decimals, I don't think you need it
2. Sorting the list work because, when sorting a list of tuple, the first element of the tuples are compared first
3. It is best to iterate over the structure in one go when possible, to make sure the order is preserved.

Comment: I need that value in first place in Xprojekti corresponds with value in first value in Yprojekti, second in Xprojekti with second in Yprojekti and so on.

Comment: And the code I gave should do that. Did you test it ? What is the result?